# How to check if value exists in catalog_category_product table Magento

Tags: magento2, database, query

How can I check if the value exists in **catalog_category_product** table Magento ?

Comment: provide more info

Comment: Asish, Am trying to update the "catalog_category_product" records for that i need to check whether record exit with "category_id"  if exit need to update the record other wise add a new record

Comment: using what?? using `sql installer` or using `model` ??

Comment: using Model  like  $model = Mage::getModel('test/test');

Answer (score -1):

```
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(product_id);
$categoryIds = $_products->getCategoryIds();
if(in_array(category_id, $categoryIds)){
 echo "value already there!";
}
else
{
echo "value not there!";
}
```

**Hope this will work for you.**